# There is no registered property exception, except there should be

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to teach myself blazor webassembly and I've hit a snag.  It's a very simple project, a Blazor Webassembly app with a few modifications.

I'm getting the error:

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property '_db' on type
'ChoresAppTheThird.Client.Pages.Users'. There is no registered service of type 
'DataAccessLibrary.IUserData'.

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property '_db' on type 
'ChoresAppTheThird.Client.Pages.Users'. There is no registered service of type 
'DataAccessLibrary.IUserData'.
```

There **is** a registered service, or there should be (from startup.cs):

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddTransient<ISqlDataAccess, SqlDataAccess>();
            services.AddTransient<IUserData, UserData>();
        }
```

And here is the page that triggers the error:

```
@page "/users"

@using DataAccessLibrary
@using DataAccessLibrary.Models

@inject IUserData _db

<h3>Users</h3>

@if (people == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (PersonModel user in people)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> @user.Name </td>
                <td> @user.Email </td>
                <td> @user.PhoneNumber </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
@code {
    private List<PersonModel> people;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        people = await _db.GetPeople();
    }

}
```

And here's IUserData/UserData:

```
    public interface IUserData
    {
        Task<List<PersonModel>> GetPeople();
        Task InsertPerson(PersonModel person);
    }

    public class UserData : IUserData
    {
        private readonly ISqlDataAccess _db;

        public UserData(ISqlDataAccess db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public Task<List<PersonModel>> GetPeople()
        {
            string sql = "select * from Users";
            return _db.LoadData<PersonModel, dynamic>(sql, new { });
        }

        public Task InsertPerson(PersonModel person)
        {
            string sql = @"insert into Users (Name, Email, PhoneNumber)
                        values (@Name, @Email, @PhoneNumber);";

            return _db.SaveData(sql, person);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  I have tried messing with the services somewhat- I've used singleton, scoped, and transient to no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is not in the right direction for a WASM project.

In WASM (remember that a WASM project is [Single Page Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/choose-between-traditional-web-and-single-page-apps)), you need to create a Rest API call from the client side to get the data from the backend (Database).

If you use the standard Blazor wizard from Visual Studio and *tick* the **ASP.NET Core Hosted** the template will create for you a complete solution, with Client, Server and Shared project.

[image]

Now you can use this scaffolder to implement you database logic on the **Server** project.
The **Client** project will call via Rest API your Web API Controller.

Look at **FetchData.razor** for the Client side:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");
    }
```

and **WeatherForecastController.cs** on the Server side:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
```

In the *Server* project you can add your database logic.

Start reading this tutorial from Syncfusion:
https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/how-to-build-a-blazor-wasm-crud-application-with-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When you have a Startup.cs in a WebAssembly project then that is in the Server part of a Hosted application.

Note that you have 3 projects: Client, Server and Shared.

Your Db is registered in the Server and not accessible in the Client. And it should not and cannot be.

The UserData class should be part of the Server project. The Client can get data through a Web API call.

The Client runs in a Browser and cannot access a database directly.